# Apache HTTPD process cumulative cpu time

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, central-processing-unit, time, process

How can I aggregate all Apache HTTPD processes' CPU time usage to be able to compare them with other running processes' (MySQL, Java, ...)? Or how much CPU time does HTTPD needs compared to MySQL for example?

"ps --cumulative", "top -S", "pidstat -T CHILD" does not help because cumulated cpu times only include exited child processes' time, and httpd processes are living quite long.

Is there an existing utility for this or I have to make one?

Comment: What about to use mod_status as I suggested to this question http://serverfault.com/questions/516484/apache2-server-using-a-lot-of-cpu/521174#521174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache server status will show you the cumulative process time(s):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html